# nameof() operator for Multiple Levels of Properties

Tags: c#, expression, nameof

What is nameof() equivalent for the following expression:

```
query.Include(x => x.Collection.Select(y => y.Property))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $"{nameof(XType.Collection)}.{nameof(CollectionType.Property)}";
```

Would probably be the closest thing?